# VideoJS issues when switching to flash programmatically

Tags: video.js

I am switching the video.js player between several different videos in different formats using `vjs.src(videoSrc)`. When I switch to an flv file this way, the flash player seems to load, but the controls are missing in chrome. In firefox the player simply says "no compatible source was found for this video". Does anything special need to be done to switch to a flash source programmatically?

Comment: can you post the actual videoSrc variable? Is it an object with the mime type specified?

Comment: yes, it is always `{ src: "http://...", type: "video/..." }`